# Cannot submit Cognito Form with radio buttons unless answer is Yes

Tags: cognito-forms

On my form I have two questions which have radio buttons with Yes/No choices. The form will not submit unless the answer is marked to "Yes".

It will keep saying that it is a required question, even if you click No or go back and forth. I also tried using the toggle style buttons, and it did the same thing.

How can I get the form to submit if the user chooses "No" from the radio button options?

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. The Yes/No field has to have a default value by design. This is because the Checkbox and Toggle cannot be blank, they have to have a True or False value.

When the Yes/No field is required the “Yes” or “True” answer is always the required answer no matter what the default answer was set to. This has been designed this way so that when the field is displayed as a checkbox a user will have to check the box acknowledging that they have read the statement.

If you need to make a Yes/No value with radio buttons you can use the Choice Field and only have two options labeled “Yes” and “No”. Then you could make the Choice Field required and not specify a default value. Either value would then be acceptable as an answer.